# C: Indexed Array for Hashtable which itself consists of N “struct nodes”: Struggling to access single elements

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

The problem is about an indexed array for a hashtable, which itself consists of a number N of “struct nodes”, see code below.
Each field of the array is the head of a linked list which is to be filled in later.

I am trying to access a field (as defined below in “struct node”) of a specific indexed element of this array.

LENGTH and N are previously defined constant integers, that is they are 45 and 5, respectively.

```
  typedef struct node
  {
      char word[LENGTH + 1];
      struct node *next;
  }
  node;

  // Hash table
  node *table[N];


     // initialize hashtable
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        (table[i]->next) = NULL;
    }
```

The code (which is obviously part of a larger program) compiles correctly but I receive a “segmentation fault” on debug here

**(table[i]->next) = NULL**

My guess is that it might be a syntax problem because I can't really see any other possible issue here.

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say it's C++, but your code is pretty much pure C.

Comment: Also, where do you initialise the contents of `table`? Where do you allocate those nodes?

Comment: @ Etienne de Martel
yes, you are probably right, I corrected this

Comment: @ Etienne de Martel   
this array will be used as pointers to link lists. The array is not supposed to use the "word" field of the struct, but only the "next" field. It uses the same struct as the (future) nodes of the linked list just for convenience, I guess.
And all the "next" fields of the array should be to NULL pointer because there is nothing to point to at this time. And this is what I am trying to do: make them point to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
node* table[N];
```

is not declaring an array of node structs, it is declaring an array of pointers to node structs. As I don't see any place where you initialize the array itself, I assume you are not doing it.

The correct way would be (modernizing your code a little):

```
struct node
{
  char word[LENGTH + 1];
  struct node *next;
};

// Hash table
std::array<node,N> table;


// initialize hashtable
for ( node& n: table )
{
    n.next = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Actually, as @ Etienne de Martel commented, my code is C, not C++.
I guess your improved code is C++, and this is why I have great problems to understand any bit of the syntax (i.e. the notation "std::" is completely foreign to me.
As you may have guessed, I am quite new to coding.

Comment: A suggestion for improvment: keep the array as storing `node *`, and `new` up some `node` objects in the loop. As it stands, this answers leaves the most important aspect implicit and without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from Jellyboy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69474309/10871073) pointed me in the right direction: I need to declare an "array of node structs", and not an "array of pointers to node structs".

So the solution is simply:

```
node table[N];      // (instead of:   node* table[N];
```

And then I am also able to initialize my hashtable, i.e. this array ("table") of N "struct nodes", and these will later serve as start points for linked lists.

I was led in the wrong direction because in the distributed "raw code" that I received in this online course, there was this statement (which included the `*`), and I didn't think I would have to change it.

And, as I said, I am really very new to coding, so bear with me.